# setting attribute in current_thread as state holder

Tags: python, multithreading, wsgi

I have a wsgi application which can potentially run in different python web server environments(cherrypy, uwsgi or gunicorn), but not greenlet-based. The application handles different paths for some REST apis and user interfaces. During any http call of the app there is a need to know, what is the context of the call, since implementation logic methods share code of API calls and UI calls and some bunch of logic which is separated in many modules should react differently depending on the context. The simple and straightforward way is to pass a parameter to implementation code, e.g. ApiCall(caller=client_service_id) or UserCall(caller=user_id), but it's a pain to propagate this parameter to all the possible modules. Is it a good solution to just set the context in the thread object like this?

```
def set_context(ctx):
    threading.current_thread().ctx = ctx

def get_context():
    return threading.current_thread().ctx
```

So call set_context somewhere in the beginning of the http call handler where we can construct the context ovject depending on the environment data, and then just use get_context() in any part of the code where we must react depending on the context. What is the best practices to achive this? Thank you!

Comment: I personally get very scared with attributes that pop-up in the middle of the execution. Can't you create your own `thread` class? (although this is just a personal opinion, and by no means a valid answer... or anything that should be taken too seriously)

Comment: Or use a queue, maybe? https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html

Comment: @BorrajaX, sorry, maybe didn't catch your idea with the own thread class, not sure if it can help for multiprocessing environment, where is the only MainThread(already created) in the worker process.